# Java: Moving arrays to different methods in regards to text

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, text-processing

I need help tweaking my code. I need to write a program that outputs the count of individual ascii characters in a txt file that the user uploads, but I'm having a lot of problems trying to get the array that I count into the GUI portion of the program that "draws" the data on the screen. 
I have the output looking how I want, but I can't figure out how to get the character count up there

I want to put the number of times a character/punction/number is used in a file that the user uploads on a graphic display. For instance, 33 or ! there are 3 instances. Or 65 A there are 4354 instances in the file. However I'm having a large problem with getting the counter to count the characters in the word correctly, and even more trouble getting the stored array of numbers of characters to the GUI (g.draw) section of the program.

Instead of a number, I just get a blank output column.

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.io.FileReader;      // both needed
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class textreader extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
    String dataFilePath = null;
    String dataFileName = null;
    int[] counter = new int[256];

    String command = "";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Frame frame = new textreader();
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setSize(1000,850);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public textreader()
    {
        setTitle("Text File Processing");

        // Menu Creation
        MenuBar mn = new MenuBar();
        setMenuBar(mn);

        // Create "File" and add it
        Menu fileMenu = new Menu("File");
        mn.add(fileMenu);

        // Create Menu Items, Add action Listener, Add to "File" Menu Group

        // Open file
        MenuItem miOpen = new MenuItem("Open");
        miOpen.addActionListener(this);
        fileMenu.add(miOpen);

        // Process file
        MenuItem miProcess = new MenuItem("Process");
        miProcess.addActionListener(this);
        fileMenu.add(miProcess);

        // Exit program
        MenuItem miExit = new MenuItem("Exit");
        miExit.addActionListener(this);
        fileMenu.add(miExit);

        // To Terminate
        WindowListener d = new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }

            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent ev)
            {
                repaint();
            }

            public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent ev)
            {
                repaint();
            }
        };

        ComponentListener k = new ComponentAdapter()
        {
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) 
            {
                repaint();           
            }
        };

        // listener registry
        this.addWindowListener(d);
        this.addComponentListener(k);
}

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ev)
    {
        // which command was issued?
        command = ev.getActionCommand();

        // act          
        if("Open".equals(command))
    {
            dataFilePath = null;
            dataFileName = null;

            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG );
            chooser.setDialogTitle("Open Data File");

            int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if( returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
            {
                dataFilePath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
                dataFileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
            }
            repaint();
        }
        else
            if("Process".equals(command))
            {
                try 
                {   
                    // Initialize
                    int[] aCount = new int[256];

                    // "Instantiate" streams
                    BufferedReader inputStream  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dataFilePath));

                    // read the file line by line and count the characters read
                    String line = null;
                    char c = 0;
                    int lineLength = 0;
                    int charValue = 0;

                    while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        // *********  process line
                        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
                        {
                            char ch = line.charAt(i);

                            if (ch >= 0 && ch <= 255)
                            {
                                counter[(int)ch]++;
                            }
                            else
                            {    // silently ignore non-ASCII characters
                            }
                            // count newline at the end
                        counter['\n']++;
                    }
                }
            }

            catch(IOException ioe)
            {
                System.out.print("You want to run that by me again?"); 
            }

        repaint();
        }
    else
        if("Exit".equals(command))
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }

}

//********************************************************
//called by repaint() to redraw the screen
//********************************************************

public void paint(Graphics g)
{               
if("Open".equals(command))
{
        // Acknowledge that file was opened
        if (dataFileName != null)
        {
            g.drawString("File --  "+dataFileName+"  -- was successfully opened", 400, 400);
        }
        else
        {
            g.drawString("NO File is Open", 400, 400);
        }

        return; 
}
else
    if("Process".equals(command))
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            {
                int x = 100;
                int y = 100;
                g.drawString("Int", x, y);
                g.drawString("Char", x+50, y);
                g.drawString("Count", x+100, y);
                g.drawLine(100, y+15, x+120, y+15);

                y = y + 30;
                int line = 0;

                for(int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
                {
                    line++;
                    g.drawString(Integer.toString(j), x, y);
                    g.drawString(Character.toString((char)j), x + 50, y);   
                    // Converts the # to a char, then to a String

                    // This part of the code adds a new column when    the flag reaches 43

                    if(line == 45)
                    {
                        x = x + 150;
                        y = 100;
                        g.drawString("Int", x, y);
                        g.drawString("Char", x+50, y);
                        g.drawString("Count", x+100, y);
                        g.drawLine(100, y+15, x+120, y+15);
                        y = y + 15;
                        line = 0;
                    }
                    y = y+15;
                }
            }
            return; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Your question is vague: "I can't figure out how to get the character count up there".  Can you provide more details, such as what you expected to happen and what actually happened.  That will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: I want to put the number of times a character/punction/number is used in a file that the user uploads on a graphic display. For instance, 33 or ! there are 3 instances. Or 65 A there are 4354 instances in the file. However I'm having a large problem with getting the counter to count the characters in the word correctly, and even more trouble getting the stored array of numbers of characters to the GUI (g.draw) section of the program

Comment: Are you aware of the `countMatches` method of the Apache `StringUtils` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add this to your code:

```
g.drawString(Integer.toString(counter[j]), x + 120, y);
```

right here (int the paint method):

```
g.drawString(Integer.toString(j), x, y);
g.drawString(Character.toString((char)j), x + 50, y);
g.drawString(Integer.toString(counter[j]), x + 120, y);
```

Comment: Thank you so so so much. I don't know how the hell i was missing that

Comment: you are welcome,BTW you don't need to repeat the outer loop 256 times! just one is enough.